# How to check Audio Signal In Video Using Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, video

I am using MATLAB 2017, I need to check that whether the selected video has audio signal or not? 
I used

```
[file path] = uigetfile('*.avi');

if(~isequal(file,0))

fullpath =strcat(path,file);
xyloObj = vision.VideoFileReader(fullpath);
infoa = info(xyloObj)
end
```

it gives error Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'vision.VideoFileReader'.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mmfileinfo`

```
[file path] = uigetfile('*.avi');
if exist(fullfile(path,file),'file')
    info= mmfileinfo(fullfile(path,file));
    isfield(info,'Audio')
end
```

Comment: @IrfanBabar Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I can't because my reputation isn't enough to upvote.